# numpy results are order dependent when they should not be

Tags: python, numpy, gpgpu

I have a (toy) dense NN implemented on numpy. Putting three vectors through through the
network, I am seeing deltas in the least-significant digits of one of the outputs if I
change the order of the inputs. E.g., swapping the 2nd and 3rd inputs:

```
xta = train_x[:,0:3]                                 # 1st 3 entries in my training set
xtb = np.array([xta[:,0], xta[:,2], xta[:,1]]).T     # swap 2nd and 3rd entries
sameness = np.array_equal(xta[:,0], xtb[:,0]) and \
        np.array_equal(xta[:,1],xtb[:,2]) and \
        np.array_equal(xta[:,2],xtb[:,1])
print(f"Is xta the 'same' as xtb? {sameness}")
print("================================")
yha = nn.forward(xta)
for i in range(yha.shape[0]):
    for j in range(yha.shape[1]):
        print(f"\tyha[{i},{j}] = {yha[i,j]}")
yhb = nn.forward(xtb)
for i in range(yhb.shape[0]):
    for j in range(yhb.shape[1]):
        print(f"\tyhb[{i},{j}] = {yhb[i,j]}")
print("================================")
```

Produces:

```
Is xta the 'same' as xtb? True
================================
yha[0,0] = 0.7205756079760192
yha[0,1] = 0.8095488210472898
yha[0,2] = 0.8604228442660007
yhb[0,0] = 0.7205756079760192
yhb[0,1] = 0.8604228442660007
yhb[0,2] = 0.8095488210472895
================================
```

The LSB of yha[0,1] does not equal the LSB of yhb[0,2]. This is a straightforward NN implementation. The first three layers are WX+b ==> RELU, the last layer is WX+b ==> SIGMOID, all implemented on numpy and executing in the GPU. The forward pass does accumulate state for use in the reverse pass, but the accumulated state is not used to calculate the output. (And, if it were, there would be a bigger difference.)

So... it looks to me like the least-significant bit can wobble depending on the order in which the operations are performed. Thoughts?

Comment: You're dealing with Neural Networks and floating point.  Your results are identical to more than ten decimal places.   Everything is fine.

Comment: Except that I am providing identical inputs to identical floating point operations--they should be deterministic. I'm puzzled that state accumulated in the GPU from prior operations is affecting the output of subsequent operations. (If, indeed, that is what I am observing.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this library, where do you import nn from? That said, I think it looks totally fine. I'm guessing there is some random initializer for the weights, so switching the order is effectively like changing the random seed. I'm actually a little surprised the results are as close as they are. You could verify by rerunning identical code without a seed and see if you see similar fluctuations.

Comment: It is not a public library; I'm implementing my own NN. Note that it is the same NN being used for all operations; the weights are not changing between invocations of forward().

Comment: @Greg.  Please take "yes" for an answer.  What you're seeing is perfectly acceptable.  Perhaps two multiplications are taking place in a different order.  Perhaps some other variable falls between two floating point values and it is causing this value to fluctuate, too.  Your results are far more stable than you have any reason to expect.

Comment: I think I will take your answer. I'll hypothesize that, with a different ordering of events, the matrixes are being allocated to different GPU units and so are being processed in a different order. Hence the non-determinism. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I like Frank Yellin's hypothesis, so will recast it as an answer:

While the operations are the same and the matrixes that are inputs to the operation are the same, the operations may process the matrix elements in a different order resulting in different rounding errors on the least significant bits.